# ZeroMQ port-forwarding in Java

Tags: java, zeromq, portforwarding, jeromq

I have a program written in Java that should send messages out via **`ZeroMQ`** to be listened and responded to by another program I have running.

The problem is that the listener is on another computer on the local network and I need to somehow perform port forwarding in `ZeroMQ` in order for the messages to be received across the network.

```
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    ZMQ.Socket requester = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
    requester.connect("tcp://192.168.78.14:5570"); //192.168.78.14 is the address of listening machine

    String msg = "Message";
    requester.send(msg.getBytes());

    byte[] reply = requester.recv();
```

When the above code is run, the program waits indefinitely for a response (that never comes) and so effectively is unresponsive. The listener is listening on `tcp://127.0.0.1:5570` for messages. Setting it to `tcp://0.0.0.0:5570` or `tcp://*:5570` which supposedly opens listening to all addresses on given port also yields nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This solution is being used in production for about the last two decades already, as large groups of spatially distributed Virtual Machines need to get similar `host:port` sessions live, independently of their actual instantiation in the respective real network address spaces</sup>

---

### Use `ssh-port-forwarding` tunnels between the hosts

The solution is in principle independent of the `ZeroMQ` framework setup.

Setup a live SSH-connection between two hosts of your wish.

On each end, provide the respective **port-forwarding** mappings, according to the `port#`-s used in **`ZeroMQ`** communication setup.

On **`host A`** `192.168.78.14` forward local port `5570` to a remote `IP:port#` target

```
L5570 forward to 192.168.78.15:5570
```

On **`host A`** a **`ZeroMQ`**-communicating pattern transparently "speaks" to local port `5570`, which is by the service of the `ssh`-tunnel forwarded to the opposite side, host **`B`** and delivered to there referred port `5570` for further socket-traffic processing.

On **`host B`** `192.168.78.15` a **`ZeroMQ`**-communicating pattern seamlessly "interacts" through the port **`5570`**, as if the communicating counterparty was "sitting" in the same "box", and processes the socket-traffic delivered actually through the `ssh`-tunnel, without knowing about such trick.

QED.

---

<sub>For one's faster and easier prototyping, one might opt to use rather `.socket(ZMQ.PAIR)` archetype, which does not introduce any high-level `ZeroMQ`-behavioural pattern and simply sends whatever the socket interface is instructed to send to the opposite side ( without any waiting for `REP`-reply to prior `REQ`-message )</sub>